# Ruby second_base dump schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Ruby on Rails and have the [second_base](https://github.com/customink/secondbase) Gem in use to connect to a second data source.  Everything works fine for `db:schema:dump` commands and everything else; however, I don't see a way to dump the schema from second_base.

When I attempt to run `bin/rake db:second_base:schema:dump` I get the following message:

> rake aborted!
>
> Don't know how to build task 'db:second_base:schema:dump' (see --tasks)
>
> (See full trace by running task with --trace)

When I use the documented `db:second_base:schema:cache:dump` it does not give me the data I am expecting.

Maybe I'm missing it on the GitHub page, but how would I go about generating a *schema.rb* file for second_base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From second_base documentation:

```
Below is a complete list of :db tasks that automatically run a mirrored
:db:second_base task. Some private or over lapping tasks, like schema 
dump/loading or db:setup, are not listed.
```

So there is no rake task for schema:dump for second_base.